# Browser History React Router

Tags: react-router, browser-history

I am trying to configure my browserHistory. My route is

```
    <Route path="/test" component = {App} />
```

It works fine if I create a link. But if I put **localhost/test** in the browser or url I get a 404 error. I assume it cant find it on the server.

Can someone please help me? I am new to react-router. Do I have to configure the server side?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as mentioned in [React Router documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory) you must configure your server so that it always returns your **index page**, no matter which path the browser requests.

Using [express](http://expressjs.com/), supposing you have a `/public/index.html` file, this would work:

```
/* Your express includes and init code would go here... */

// Serve static assets normally
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

// Handle every other route with index.html, which will contain
// a script tag to your application's JavaScript file(s).
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})
```

The important thing is `app.get('*', ...`, which will return the same thing (in this case your `index.html` file), no matter which path is requested from your browser.

Hope that helps.